# Extract the subset of a dataframe based with values unique from other two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three dataframes `df1`,`df2`,`df3`. I would like to identify the value(s) in `col1` of `df2` not present in `col1` of `df1` and/or `col1` of `df3`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','C','E'),col2=c(4,8,2))
df1

df2 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','B','C','E','G','I'),col2=c(4,8,2,6,1,9))
df2

df3 <- data.frame(col1=LETTERS[3:26],col2=sample(3:26))
df3

# Expected output
#2    B    8
```

What I have done?

```
table(df2$col1 %in% df1$col1)
# FALSE  TRUE 
#    3     3

df2[df2$col1 %in% df1$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#1    A    4
#3    C    2
#4    E    6

df2[!df2$col1 %in% df1$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#2    B    8
#5    G    1
#6    I    9

table(df2$col1 %in% df3$col1)
#FALSE  TRUE 
#    2     4

df2[df2$col1 %in% df3$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#3    C    2
#4    E    6
#5    G    1
#6    I    9

df2[!df2$col1 %in% df3$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#1    A    4
#2    B    8
```

In a wrong approach,

```
df2[!df2$col1[!df2$col1 %in% df1$col1] %in% df3$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#1    A    4
#4    E    6
```

How to avoid the repetition of the indices?

Is there any better approach than the below?

```
df2[!df2$col1 %in% df1$col1,][!df2$col1[!df2$col1 %in% df1$col1] %in% df3$col1,]
#  col1 col2
#2    B    8
```

While the correct approach,

```
df2[!(df2$col1 %in% df1$col1 | df2$col1 %in% df3$col1),]
#  col1 col2
#2    B    8
```

Comment: You can use `anti_join` or `setdiff` from `dplyr`

Comment: do you mean `anti_join(anti_join(df2,df1,by='col1'),df3,by='col1')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df3) %>%
           anti_join(df2, ., by = "col1")
#  col1 col2
#1    B    8
```